# How to get all elements from this array with ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Want to get all the unique ids from this type of array:

```
[[], [1], [2], [1, 3, 2], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1], [2, 4], [3], [2]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ids" – all the numbers or maybe just the first number in each subarray? What's your expected result and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given `a` your array

```
a.flatten.uniq
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[[], [1], [2], [1, 3, 2], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1], [2, 4], [3], [2]].
  reduce([]) { |acc, e| acc | e }
  # or (credit goes to @Stefan)
  # reduce([], :|)

#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: in emoji style: `ary.reduce([], :|)` 

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake a Micro-Benchmark that shows yet another solution: use inplace versions of `uniq!` which will be slightly faster.

If it is okay to change the original array you can also use

`array.flatten!
array.uniq!`

but be aware that this modifies the `array` and this might be unwanted, especially if it is a paramter to a method.

Here is a micro-benchmark:

```
require "benchmark/ips"
# ARRAY = [[], [1], [2], [1, 3, 2], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1], [2, 4], [3], [2]].freeze
ARRAY = [[], [1], [2], [1, 3, 2], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1], [2, 4], [3], [2], [], [1], [2], [1, 3, 2], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1], [2, 4], [3], [2], [], [1], [2], [1, 3, 2], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1], [2, 4], [3], [2], [], [1], [2], [1, 3, 2], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1], [2, 4], [3], [2],[], [1], [2], [1, 3, 2], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1], [2, 4], [3], [2]].freeze

Benchmark.ips do |x|
    x.compare!

    x.report("flatten.uniq") { ARRAY.flatten.uniq }
    x.report("flatten.uniq!") { ARRAY.flatten.uniq! }
    x.report("reduce") { ARRAY.reduce([]) { |acc, e| acc | e } }
end
```

And here are the results:

```
Comparison:
       flatten.uniq!:   107888.3 i/s
        flatten.uniq:   105813.6 i/s - same-ish: difference falls within error
              reduce:    49892.6 i/s - 2.16x  slower
```

Note that the `reduce` variant might actually be faster if there are fewer elements. But it will only work with one level of nesting whereas the other versions will work for all levels. So `[[[1]]]` will not work with the `reduce` variant.